# Backslash at end of string filepath in CSV stopping replacement

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with a list of full file paths. It looks something like this:

```
C:\Folder1\Subfolder1\file1.txt
C:\Folder1\Subfolder2\file2.txt
C:\Folder1\Subfolder3\file3.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove the "C:\Folder1\" from the string so that I'm only left with:

```
Subfolder1\file1.txt
Subfolder2\file2.txt
Subfolder3\file3.txt
```

I came up with the following script:

```
(Get-Content c:\test.csv) | % {$_.Replace('C:\\Folder1\\','')}
```

When I run this, the replace does not work at all.

If I leave the `\` off the end of the path, it works except it keeps a backslash in front of the Subfolder name:

```
\Subfolder1\file1.txt  
\Subfolder2\file2.txt  
\Subfolder3\file3.txt
```

I have tried a number of different methods to get this to work, including adding more backslashes to escape the backslash and changing the single quotes to double-quotes around the string I want to replace, but nothing is working.

Would someone point me in the right direction of what I am doing wrong?

---

Edited to add:

Boxdog's comment had me look at my initial export CSV in Notepad. This CSV is an export of the Fullname from a directory. When I look at it in Notepad++, the records look like this:

```
"FullName"
"C:\Folder1\Subfolder1\file1.txt"
"C:\Folder1\Subfolder2\file2.txt"
"C:\Folder1\Subfolder3\file3.txt"
```

I'm thinking the double-quotes are causing the problem. If so, how do I remedy that?

Comment: If you just want to replace the Path, you could try `(Get-Content C:\test.csv) -replace "C:\\Folder1\\", ""`

Comment: Your original code works fine for me if I simply drop the extra backslash.  e.g. `$_.replace('C:\Folder1\','')`.

Comment: Razorfen, I tried your example but it did not work for me.

Comment: Boxdog, I ended up with a "Regular expression pattern is not valid" error message.

Comment: What is the trailing string of the end of path ? two or four backslashes? I edited the post and put them into code, but you had it escaped in quotes, so now it seems to be like four backslashes.

Comment: Boxdog, sorry--I had another window open with a different script. I tried your suggestion on the correct window but it still did not work for me.

Comment: XXX, I've tried both 2 backslashes and 4 backslashes, but neither worked for me.

Comment: Possibly your text file has some extra formatting/hidden characters or has an odd encoding problem.  I simply copied the text from your post and saved as a basic ANSI file in Notepad and it worked straight away.

Comment: Boxdog, you got me thinking--the CSV file is an export of the fullname, and when I look at it in Notepad++ there are double-quotes around each entry. Would that have an effect?

Comment: I just tried adding "% {$_.replace('"',"")}" before the Replace, but that didn't work either. :(

Comment: The code you posted would not replace anything at all b/c `Replace()` does simple string replacements. boxdog's first comment would fix that. If that gives you an error *"Regular expression pattern is not valid"* you are not running the code you posted in your question. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, then update your question with *that* exact code and the full error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Given your above example, I've created a file called `test.csv` and looped over it with a simple `foreach` like so:

```
$input_file = Import-Csv .\test.csv

foreach ($row in $input_file) {
    # Replacing C:\FolderX\SubfolderX\ where X could be any character
    $trimmed_path = $row.FullName -replace "C:\\Folder.*\\Subfolder.*\\", ""

    Write-Host "Trimmed Path: $trimmed_path"
}
```

The current `Write-Host` is just for demo-purposes - you can obviously do whatever you want :-)

> Please note that I've used the `.` as a "Wildcard" in the replacement-statement to allow any character after "Folder" and "Subfolder" in the path-name

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. I keep forgetting that PS imports everything as an object, so even though the data look like strings on the screen, they are not strings.

Once I remembered that I used an Out-String command to convert the objects to strings, which took care of the problem.

I appreciate everyone's help with this!